# Laravel Nova: Bypass the search with Scout

Tags: laravel-nova

How to disable searching for a resource with Scout without removing the Searchable trait from the resource model?

I want to deliberately bypass the Scout search inside Nova.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your Nova Resource

```
public static function usesScout()
{
    return false;
}
```